# Problem storing coordinates

Tags: iphone, gps

I'm doing the following to store the longitude and latitude of a location in a custom (NSManagedObject) Bookmark object:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

// Set bookmark variables.
[bookmark setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude]];
[bookmark setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude]];
```

But something goes amiss along the way, and printing out the values of coordinate and bookmark yields this:

```
2011-03-09 12:56:30.793 XXXXXX[562:307] 55.615258, 12.985627 <- coordinate
2011-03-09 12:56:30.798 XXXXXX[562:307] 0.000000, 12.985626 <- bookmark
```

What happened to my Bookmark?

Bookmark.h

```
@interface Bookmark :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * longText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * shortText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;

@end
```

Bookmark.m

```
#import "Bookmark.h"

@implementation Bookmark 

@dynamic dateCreated;
@dynamic longText;
@dynamic shortText;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic latitude;

@end
```

Comment: how does your `bookmark` object look like?

Comment: Can we see the setLongtitude-method? :-)

Comment: I'm sure the `setLongitude:` method has a problem..

Comment: Pls post more details about bookMark

Comment: That was also my first assessment, but seeing as passing the bookmark on and later showing it in a mapView works without a problem, I honestly have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything seems to be fine from the code I suggest you take a look at managed object model. Probably entity with wrong data type? Also it could be that your `NSLog` (or other logging statement) has wrong placeholder in format (like `%f` instead of `%@`, since property is `NSNumber` object).

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed me using %f rather than %@.